# mongodb performance issue when fetching facet count and data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new using MongoDB.
I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58204f60536d1a27736d512b"),
    "last_name" : "Vinaykumar",
    "university_name" : "Osmania University",
    "job_483" : 1,
    "xiith_mark" : 0,
    "id" : "3305775",
    "first_name" : "V",
    "course_name" : "Diploma",
    "institute_name_string" : "Govt.Polytechnic,Kothagudem",
    "profile_percentage" : 60,
    "xiith_mark_type" : "Percentage",
    "xth_mark_type" : "Percentage",
    "date_of_birth" : "11-March-1995",
    "xth_mark" : 0,
    "last_login" : 1379565790,
    "percentage" : 76,
    "job_details" : [
    {
        "status" : NumberLong(0),
        "applied_date" : NumberLong(1476703354),
        "contact_viwed_status" : 0,
        "label_name" : [ ],
        "questionnaire_status" : 0,
        "batch_id" : null,
        "owner_type" : "searches",
        "call_letter" : null,
        "owner_id" : NumberLong(465)
    },
    {
        "status" : NumberLong(0),
        "applied_date" : NumberLong(1477051963),
        "contact_viwed_status" : 0,
        "label_name" : [ ],
        "questionnaire_status" : 0,
        "batch_id" : null,
        "owner_type" : "searches",
        "call_letter" : null,
        "owner_id" : NumberLong(482)
    },
    {
        "status" : NumberLong(0),
        "applied_date" : NumberLong(1477052973),
        "contact_viwed_status" : 0,
        "label_name" : [ ],
        "questionnaire_status" : 0,
        "batch_id" : null,
        "owner_type" : "searches",
        "call_letter" : null,
        "owner_id" : NumberLong(483)
   }
   ],
   "branch_name" : "Electrical & Electronics",
   "candidate_state_name" : "Andhra Pradesh",
   "candidate_city_name_string" : "Andhra Pradesh-other",
   "10" : 10,
   "12" : 12,
   "gender" : "Male",
   "fw_id" : "FW15651132",
   "cgpa" : 0,
   "picture_path" : "",
   "hq_passout_year" : 2013
}
```

I need to find data from this db with facet count .
**Need facet count for following fields**

- job_details.status ,  job_details.label_name, 
  job_details.contact_viwed_status,   candidate_city_name_string,
  course_name,   hq_passout_year,   branch_name , 
  candidate_sublocation_name_string ,  skill

And total matching count and data with limit

I did separate query for each facet and one query for total count and one query for data
Total   9+1+1=11 querys

**Query's are**

facet query's for job_details.status and job_details.label_name and job_details.contact_viwed_status did like this

```
db.Response.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"$and":[{"job_details.owner_id" : 428},    
    {"job_details.owner_type" : 'searches'}]}}, 
    {"$unwind": "$job_details" }, 
    {"$group": {"_id":"$job_details.status","count": {"$sum": 1 }} }
    ])
```

other 6 facet query's like this

```
db.Response.aggregate([ {"$and":[{"job_details.owner_id" : 428},{"job_details.owner_type" : 'searches'}]},
                {"$group": {"_id":"$candidate_city_name_string","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}] )
```

**query for collecting data**

```
 db.Response.aggregate([
              {"$and":[{"job_details.owner_id" : 428}{"job_details.owner_type" : 'searches'}]},
              {"$limit":25},``
              { "$skip":0} ,
              {"$unwind":"$job_details"}])
```

**query for collecting total count**

```
db.Response.find({"$and":[{"job_details.owner_id" : 428},{"job_details.owner_type" : 'searches'}]}).count()
```

**Total 3+9+1+1=11 Querys**
  So performance is very very low . Is possible to make this 11 query to single query or how can i improve the performance.
please help.

Comment: are you asking for $facet ? (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23654)

Comment: yes. i need facet count , total count and data

Comment: when i using $fecet agot the error. Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$facet',

Comment: MongoDB 3.4 is needed